# How do you call web service in android such that it will continue waiting for response even when activity is on background?

Tags: android, web-services, service, android-activity, android-asynctask

What approach do I have to take if I need to connect to a web service and make sure it will continue downloading even after the screen has been rotated or a phone call suddenly pops up or the activity has been put on the background?

I've read from some of the answers here that it is either you use AsyncTask or a Service to connect to the web service. Is it really the proper approach when connecting to web service? What is the more suggested approach and the commonly used approach? I'll appreciate it if you could also give me some explanation and sample codes regarding the approach that you will be suggesting.

Comment: What do you doubt about the approaches you've already received as suggestions?

Comment: @Heath: While they seem to be a good solution, they also have some disadvantages. I would like to quote a comment given by one user here regarding using a service: "I've tried this before and it has 1 major flaw. I used a BroadcastReceiver to notify the ListActivity that the query was finished and to hand the data to the ListActivity. However, the BroadcastReceiver is unregistered during onPause(), which means..." As such, I would like to know which is the more preferred approach of the 2 or if there is a better approach? And if someone could kindly elaborate on the 2 approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your requirements:

**Service**
If your request is taking a long time to finish and your application is heavily depending on the result (persistent data) I would suggest to use a service because the android system can decide to kill an application which was pushed to the background and your request will be simply gone.

**AsyncTask**
For small requests with data which your application is only needing for a current state (data which can pe thrown away after real application close) I would use a AsyncTask. This could get really tricky to handle when orientation changes occur so I provide an example (*note* - it's a blueprint to get the idea, not a final solution).

**When is my Application and my AsyncTask getting killed?**
When you push your application to the background it will be still active. If you use antoher application and this request more memory, the android system can dicide to kill your *active* application to free needed resources. From this moment your activity and your task is gone. But there is still a chance for the task to finish and persit it's results in a database or on the SD card.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    private MyReqeustTask mRequestTask;

    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
         // your activity setup

         // get your running task after orientation change
         mRequestTask = (MyRequestTask) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();

         if (mRequestTask != null) {
             mRequestTask.mActivity = new WeakReference<MyActivity>(this);
             processRequest();
         }
    }

    // call that somewhere - decide what implementation pattern you choose
    // if you need more than a single request - be inventive ;-)
    public startRequest() {
        mRequestTask = new MyRequestTask();
        mRequestTask.mActivity = new WeakReference<MyActivity>(this);
        mRequestTaks.execute(your, params);
    }

    // this is a request to process the result form your actual request
    // if it's still running, nothing happens
    public processResult() {
        if (mRequestTask == null || mRequest.getStatus() != Status.FINISHED) {
            return;
        }

        Result result = mRequest.getResult();
        // update and set whatever you want here
        mRequestTask = null;
    }

    public Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        // retain task to get it back after orientation change
        return mRequestTask;
    }

    private static MyRequestTaks extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

        WeakReference<MyActivity> mActivity;

        protected Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
            // do your request here
            // don't ever youe mActivity in here, publish updates instead!
            // return your final result at the end
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Progress... progress) {
            MyActivity activity = mActivity.get();

            if (activity != null) {
                // do whatever your want to inform activity about undates
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Result result) {
            MyActivity activity = mActivity.get();

            if (activity != null) {
                // this will update your activity even if it is paused
                activity.processRequest();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! My application heavily depends on the response of the web service. I have no control over how long it will take for the request to finish as I will only be connecting to a 3rd party web service. But I do not need my connection to the web service to persist when my application is dead. That is, when my application is close forcefully or close via the back button of the Android device. In fact, I have to close my connection to the web service if the user decides to close the application. -Please see continuation below.-

Comment: Do AsyncTask also get killed when the Application is put on background? Based from my situation, is it still better for me to use Service? Or will it be better for me to use AsyncTask?

Comment: Updated my answer. If the request is just a matter of seconds (maybe 5-10) I think it would be an overkill to use a service.

Comment: Most likely, the request will only take few seconds. My only concern with AsyncTask is I am afraid that it won't run if the application is on background. But since you said that it will remain active even when the application is on background, then I think in the case of my application, it will be better for me to use AsyncTask. I will experiment on using AsyncTask for now. Thanks for your advice!