# Object scope and aggressive cleanup on paused Activity instances

Tags: java, android, android-activity, garbage-collection, android-asynctask

I have an Activity that contains an AsyncTask as an inner class (as I have seen in most examples).  If I fire the AsyncTask and then pause the Activity by navigating away from it, the AsyncTask continues to execute.  As I understand it, this is normal and expected behavior.

There is a member variable in the Activity that is being accessed by a method call from the AsyncTask.  I just got a NullPointerException on it while the AsyncTask was executing in the background while its Activity was paused, which seems to me that it was collected by the GC when the Activity was paused.  It would seem to me that the object should not be considered out of scope.  There is code still running in the Activity, so why would the Activity's member variables start getting cleaned up already?

What is the recommended usage of Activity member variables being accessed via AsyncTasks that are inner classes of the Activity?

Here is a sample of the kind of relationships my objects have

```
public class MyActivity {

    MyCustomService myCustomService;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.some_layout);

        myCustomService = ServiceLocator.getInstance(MyCustomService.class);
    }

private class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... arg0) {     

        String data = someOtherService.fetchSomeData(); 
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        refreshControls(result);
    }       
}

private void refreshControls(String result) {   
    // this is where the object is null after aggressive cleanup
    myCustomService.someMethod();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what is causing the `NullPointerException`.

But you might want to check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549996/how-do-you-call-web-service-in-android-such-that-it-will-continue-waiting-for-res/7550502#7550502) for a `AsyncTask` which is not a inner class of the activity but `static`. Inner async tasks which are started are leaking the context / activity as long as they are running. This might be no problem for short running tasks but if it stucks or performs for a long time it is leaking memory for that time.

This *might* imply the answer to your question...

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't really need to provide a stacktrace, as I can explain exactly what is happening and the stacktrace doesn't really say much.  Normally, this object is in scope and not pointing at a null reference.  However, when I pause the activity and move around the app using up more memory when the system is already low on memory, the system will garbage collect this member variable of my activity because the activity is paused.  I have tested that there's not a null ref under normal execution.  My question is, where should this object live?  Can I simply mark it final?

Comment: Or, I just check for null.  If the object is null, the activity is paused and I shouldn't execute the code (no need to update the UI).  And then I can grab a reference to my object in onResume instead of onCreate so that I can be assured that I always have a valid object instance

Comment: Hmm seems to be very odd. If your task is running and certainly does refernce the activity as long it exists, the GC shouldn't be able to trash your activity and so it's attributes. Are you sure that your not disabling `myCustomService` on pause or it got disabled somehow?

Comment: No, I have seen this before but never so specifically during development. I have gotten this kind of behavior randomly in the field for released apps, but I have a specific repeatable scenario now. This is absolutely as it is described, and my question is how to organize my object graph now knowing this. The difference between this app and the released app where I have seen it in the past is that this new app uses a lot of memory so it's easier to repeat. The other one was light but GC'ed probably on older devices so I couldn't duplicate it. I'll probably proceed as described in comment 2 ^